# Parallel consuming messages from one queue

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, activemq-classic

I have one queue with `N` messages. Now I would like to create a console application (consumer), that create a given number of tasks/threads and each thread would take 1 message from queue, process it and take a new message... until queue is empty.

Up to this point, this is what I have:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var runner = new Runner();
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { runner.ReceiveMessageFromServer(); });
    }
}
```

and

```
public class QRegistrator : IDisposable
{
    private const string activeMqUri = "activemq:tcp://localhost:61616";

    private readonly IConnection _connection;

    private readonly ISession _session;

    public QRegistrator(/*string activeMqUri*/)
    {
        var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(activeMqUri);
        _connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        _connection.Start();
        _session = _connection.CreateSession();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _connection?.Close();
    }

    public IMessageConsumer CreateConsumer(string queueName, string topicName)
    {
        //there have to be new session for each concurrent consumer
        var session = _connection.CreateSession();
        var queue = new ActiveMQQueue(queueName);
        var consumer = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(topicName) ? session.CreateConsumer(queue) : session.CreateConsumer(queue, $"topic = '{topicName}'");
        return consumer;
    }
}
```

and in class `Runner`

```
public void ReceiveMessageFromServer()
{
    var consumer = _registrator.CreateConsumer("myQueue", null);

    while (true)
    {
        ITextMessage message = consumer.Receive() as ITextMessage;
        if (message == null)
        {
            break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Received message with ID:   " + message.NMSMessageId);
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```

But when I run this code, sometimes it does not create a connection, sometimes it does not create a session etc. I really don’t understand. When I try without the for cycle (but still a task()) it behaves the same. When I try without task, and call only `runner.ReceiveMessageFromServer()` it works OK. Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you have multiple threads sharing a `runner`, is runner thread safe? Also you don't wait for the threads to complete before ending the app.

Comment: I don't think you're going to get any performance increase from attempting parallel dequeues from the mq (and quite possibly run into trouble). I would dequeue using a single thread into a local, thread-safe queue, then process the messages in the local queue in parallel.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you are right ! What a silly mistake. I fixed it, but now, when I run program, only 1 task receive message from queue and other tasks are waiting untill this task is done, then next task receive message. What I have to do to make them run in parallel ?

Comment: your problem is the prefetchPolicy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side notes: you do not wait for your tasks in `Main` method, you can do that with [`Task.WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall.aspx) method, which will block the main thread until all the messages are delivered. Also, [avoid the usage the `StartNew` method](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), it's better to use `Task.Run` in general.

Now, back to messages. According the [current docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#concurrency):

> Concurrency Considerations for Consumers
>
> Each `IConnection` instance is, in the current implementation, backed by a **single background thread** that reads from the socket and dispatches the resulting events to the application.
>
> As of version `3.5.0` application callback handlers can invoke **blocking** operations (such as `IModel.QueueDeclare` or `IModel.BasicCancel`). `IBasicConsumer` callbacks are invoked **concurrently**.

So, according [this question and answers there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4444174/213550), you need to use other class for your consumer: [`EventingBasicConsumer`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dotnet-api-guide.html#basic-consume), like this:

```
var channel = _connection.CreateModel();
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
consumer.Received += (ch, ea) =>
    {
        var body = ea.Body;
        // ... process the message
        channel.BasicAck(ea.DeliveryTag, false);
    };
String consumerTag = channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer);
```

In this case you'll got the message in event-based fashion without blocking the channel.

Other example can be found [here](https://dotnetcodr.com/2016/08/10/messaging-with-rabbitmq-and-net-review-part-5-one-way-messaging-with-an-event-based-consumer/) or [here](http://www.jarloo.com/listening-to-rabbitmq-events/). A great reference for messaging in .Net can be found here in [Andras Nemes' blog](https://dotnetcodr.com/messaging/).

Answer (score 2):

your problem is the prefetchPolicy.

```
persistent queues (default value: 1000)
non-persistent queues (default value: 1000)
persistent topics (default value: 100)
non-persistent topics (default value: Short.MAX_VALUE - 1)
```

all messages was dispatched to the first connected consumer and when another one connects he don't receive messages,  so to change this behavior if you have concurrent consumer for a queue you need to set prefetchPolicy to a lower value than default. for example add this `jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1` to the uri config in activemq.xml or set it on the client url like this

i dont know if it is possible with C# but try this

```
private const string activeMqUri = "activemq:tcp://localhost:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=1";
```

if it is not working you can set it on the broker side by adding this to activemq.xml file :

```
<destinationPolicy>
    <policyMap>
      <policyEntries>
        <!--  http://activemq.apache.org/per-destination-policies.html -->
        <policyEntry queue=">" queuePrefetch="1" > 
        </policyEntry>
      </policyEntries>
    </policyMap>
</destinationPolicy>
```

> Large prefetch values are recommended for high performance with high
>   message volumes. However, for lower message volumes, where each
>   message takes a long time to process, the prefetch should be set to 1.
>   This ensures that a consumer is only processing one message at a time.
>   Specifying a prefetch limit of zero, however, will cause the consumer
>   to poll for messages, one at a time, instead of the message being
>   pushed to the consumer.

Take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html

And

http://activemq.apache.org/destination-options.html